# Why is my choropleth not showing anything?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, choropleth

I want to show a map of the police deaths by states in the US.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd  #manipulation des donnees
import plotly.express as px

file="../data/PoliceDeaths.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None)
df = pd.read_csv('deathbystate.csv', index_col=None)

state_data = pd.DataFrame()
state_data = data.state.value_counts().rename_axis('state_code').reset_index(name='number_of_deaths')

print(state_data)


fig = px.choropleth(state_data,
                    locations='state_code', 
                    locationmode="USA-states", 
                    color='number_of_deaths',
                    color_continuous_scale="Viridis_r", 
                    scope="usa") 

fig.show()
```

My "state_data" dataFrame looks like this when printed :

```
   state_code  number_of_deaths
0          TX              1880
1          CA              1639
2          NY              1574
3          US              1225
4          IL              1073
5          PA               901
6          OH               834
7          FL               820
8          KY               772
9          GA               698
10         MO               666
11         TN               607
12         MI               574
13         NC               549
14         AL               537
15         VA               523
16         OK               496
17         NJ               485
18         LA               470
19         IN               434
20         PR               363
21         SC               362
22         MA               360
23         MD               325
24         CO               305
25         WA               290
26         AR               284
27         RR               280
28         WI               275
29         AZ               273
30         MS               261
31         KS               257
32         MN               244
33         WV               208
34         IA               197
35         OR               182
36         NM               151
37         CT               144
38         DC               128
39         UT               128
40         MT               128
41         NV               120
42         NE               110
43         ME                86
44         ID                64
45         WY                57
46         HI                56
47         ND                55
48         SD                53
49         TR                51
50         RI                50
51         AK                48
52         NH                46
53         DE                41
54         VT                26
55         VI                14
56         GU                12
57         CZ                 3
58         AS                 3
59         MP                 3
```

I looked how to do this and I can't find the reason why my map is empty.
I though it would be the state_code that would be wrong but they are apparently right.
Do you know why is my map empty when I run my code ?
Looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9THwH.jpg

Comment: Can you provide some of the deathbystate.csv data ? in csv form that will help to run the code

Comment: It should work just fine if the DataFrame is as it is printed out here. What is the Plotly version you're using?

Comment: @HamzaNABIL here it is : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e852d1d7992a582d5f8844199a506d5920220521090700/752a25

Comment: @Kaymal It is the last version + I tried with this example and it worked just fine : https://towardsdatascience.com/simplest-way-of-creating-a-choropleth-map-by-u-s-states-in-python-f359ada7735e

Comment: @Sadeuh I tried to plot the US map with `state_data` and it is working fine. You may want to check "state_code" column if it has empty characters etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @Sadeuh I tried to plot the US map with state_data and it is working
> fine. You may want to check "state_code" column if it has empty
> characters etc. –  Kaymal  May 21 at 21:41

It was an empty character present before every state_code.